# How to choose the penalty coefficient when solving constrained optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, constraints

I was wondering why don't we select a very large number to a penalty function $c$ of the augmented function $f(x) + cP(x)$ instead of doing algorithms to increase c slowly? I know that as $c$ is large enough, the sharpness of the curve decreases.

More information from my reply on a comment after editing:

It's a general question for penalty method in solving optimization problem. You know, penalty method uses an augmented function θ(c,x)=f(x)+cP(x) to optimize the function f(x) under some constraints g(x). P(x) is the penalty function. so if we draw cP(x) with respect to x, it appears as we increase c, more accuracy and less sharpness of this curve. In numerical analysis, as I see, they tend to use algorithms using SUMT technique by increasing c as steps. The question is why? Why don't we set c for example 10000 directly without needing to iteration

Comment: Can you please add more context? What kind of problem are you talking about? Penalized least squares? And which curve's "sharpness" are you talking about?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio It's a general question for penalty method in solving optimization problem. You know, penalty method uses an augmented function $\theta(c,x) = f(x) + cP(x)$ to optimize the function f(x) under some constraints g(x). P(x) is the penalty function. so if we draw cP(x) with respect to x, it appears as we increase c, more accuracy and less sharpness of this curve. In numerical analysis, as I see, they tend to use algorithms using SUMT technique by increasing c as steps. The question is why? Why don't we set c for example 10000 directly without needing to iterations.

Comment: Large penalty value results in ill-conditioned problem, which is therefore difficult to reliably and accurately solve. By increasing penalty slowly, you can use the optimal solution of the previous problem as a starting point for the new, more ill-conditioned problem.  But better to use other approaches instead, https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/institute-for-data-systems-and-society/ids-338j-multidisciplinary-system-design-optimization-spring-2010/lecture-notes/MITESD_77S10_lec08.pdf